# NPE on FirebasePerformance.isPerformanceCollectionEnabled() with Firebase Performance and AndroidX

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-performance

Using

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6
```

and using AndroidX

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Crash with exception on application start.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.perf.FirebasePerformance.isPerformanceCollectionEnabled()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzd.zzbe(Unknown Source:195)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzd.zzbd(Unknown Source:44)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source:202)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zze.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

If I disable proguard with `minifyEnabled false` - it works, but that is not an option.

Comment: Please file a bug report with Firebase.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Answer (score -2):

Updating proguard rules to include

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.**
```

fixes the issue.
Also filed a bug report.

Comment: But why crashing the debug build?